# How to Make a graph of consecutive values in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, grafana, snmp

In a Debian Os target, I want to calculate BandWidth utilization "%" on a 1-minute interval and generate a graph of these BW values over 1Hr time window using Prometheus.

"60 minutes = 60 different values of BW"

I configured snmp_exporter to scrape snmp_agent metrics such as ifHCInOctets from the target server and here's the equation:

`Interface In Utilization % =`

`((( [Total Sent packets in Bytes "ifHCInOctets_time2" - Total Sent packets in Bytes "ifHCInOctets _time1"] * 8 "Bytes into Bits") / ▲time "60s") / Maximum-Bandwidth "in bits/sec") * 100 "%"`

How can I apply this equation in ▲time=60s intervals and apply it for a 1H time-window and depict these 60 values of BW consecutively in a Prometheus graph
[image]

Answer (score 0):

PromQL expression should looks like this:

`(rate(ifHCOutOctets[1m]) * 8) / (ifHighSpeed * 1000000) * 100`

If you want to restrict to particular interface, add filter like

`(rate(ifHCOutOctets{ifIndex="0"}[1m]) * 8) / (ifHighSpeed{ifIndex="0"} * 1000000) * 100`